# Reactjs Disabling Imported Scripts After Redirection

Tags: reactjs

In `public/index.html`:

I imported the following (in the `<head>` tag):

```
<script src="./arquivos/js/menu.js"></script>
```

In my file login.js - After all true conditions:

```
render() {
    const { varRedirect } = this.state;
    if ( varRedirect) {
        return <Redirect to='/home'/>;
    }
```

My file Home.js depends on the imported script in index.html
But behaves like I'm not imported.

If I change the code to call the Home page without redirection, everything works fine!

Comment: What is inside `./arquivos/js/menu.js`?

Comment: Please show the relevant bits of `index.html` that show how `menu.js`, `login.js` and `home.js` relate to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, in menu.js there is jQuery, and I've learned that this doesn't work very well with React! I will use bulma or React-Bootstrap to solve.